# XDSoft DateTimePicker not showing correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the [XDSoft DateTimePicker](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) and I'm having an issue with none of the calendar text/time text showing as seen below.  I installed the js and css files into the correct dir's I would think and the jquery to call the window is atleast calling it but I can't figure out why it wouldn't show the text.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8q527Le1/) of my issue.

```
SO is giving me an error saying i need to accompany code, but I thought that's what the jsfiddle link was for.
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: have you included the css correctly ?

Comment: For better understanding, Please provide a **working demo** (*code snippet,jsfiddle ...*)

Comment: @KishoreSahas, as far as I can tell yes. Rendered in the source of my page on load at the topic under all the other CSS file link's is:

    <link href="/static/css/jquery.datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: @KishoreSahas, jsfiddle added

Comment: it is because you have add the wrong js file , include `/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js` , see this https://jsfiddle.net/8q527Le1/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because wrong js file is included. 
You have included `jquery.datetimepicker.js` instead of  `jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/jquery.datetimepicker.css"/ >
<script src="/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>
```

[image]

Note : the file will be inside the folder `build`

demo : 
https://jsfiddle.net/8q527Le1/1/